# Where SharePoint store raiting values?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In SPS there is rating feature (http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/12/02/how-to-use-rating-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx). I set up - all works. Now I need to find out who voted and I can't find where these values are stored. I looked in WSS_Content_FULL DB with no success. Can anyone tell me which DB and table SP use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, ratings are stored in the User Profile Service App in the Social database.